# "MulterError: Unexpected field" using nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

Im trying to save an image in a sql db but it gives me `MulterError: Unexpected field` , I did the same thing with other cases and it worked...so idk.
H E L P!!

```
<label id="divisionIdLabel" for="divisionIdInput">Division Name:</label>
<input type="text" id="divisionIdInput" name="divisionId" aria-labelledby="divisionIdLabel">

<label id="imageLabel" for="imageInput">Image:</label>
<input type="file" id="imageInput" name="image" aria-labelledby="imageLabel">
```

```
let forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
let divisionIdInput = form.querySelector('#divisionIdInput');
let imageInput = form.querySelector('#imageInput');

formData.append('image', imageInput.files[0], imageInput.files[0].name);

const divisionId = divisionIdInput.value;
fetch(`/divisionData/${divisionId}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData,
})
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Error inserting data');
    return response.text();  // Read the response as text
  })
  .then(responseText => {
    console.log('Response from server:', responseText);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

```
app.post('/divisionData/:divisionId', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    const image = req.file.buffer;
    const contentType = req.file.mimetype;
    const { divisionId } = req.body;

    // Check if any of the values are null
    if (divisionId === undefined || image === undefined) {
        res.send('All fields must have values.');
        return;
    }

    const insert_user_query = "INSERT INTO divisions (divisionId, image, contentType) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    const values = [divisionId, image, contentType];
    conn.query(insert_user_query, values, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Database error:", err);
            return res.json({ error: "Failed while inserting data into database! Try to send files again." });
        }

        return res.json({ success: true });
    });
});
```

I dont understand why it gives me in the client console:
`POST http://localhost:8081/divisionData/(the divisionId that I inserted) 500 (Internal Server Error)` `Error: Error: Error inserting data at homeSettings.js:31:37`

and in the server console:

```
MulterError: Unexpected field
```

Answer (score 0):

you should change the `image` to `file` in frontend side:

```
let forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
let divisionIdInput = form.querySelector('#divisionIdInput');
let imageInput = form.querySelector('#imageInput');

const formData = new FormData(); // Create a FormData object

formData.append('file', imageInput.files[0], imageInput.files[0].name);

const divisionId = divisionIdInput.value;
fetch(`/divisionData/${divisionId}`, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formData, // Let the browser set the correct Content-Type and boundary
})
  .then(response => {
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Error inserting data');
    return response.text();  // Read the response as text
  })
  .then(responseText => {
    console.log('Response from server:', responseText);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

and also you should wrapp your express function in try-catch scope, to find problems in backend side:

```
app.post('/divisionData/:divisionId', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
    try{
    const image = req.file.buffer;
    const contentType = req.file.mimetype;
    const { divisionId } = req.body;

    // Check if any of the values are null
    if (divisionId === undefined || image === undefined) {
        res.send('All fields must have values.');
        return;
    }

    const insert_user_query = "INSERT INTO divisions (divisionId, image, contentType) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    const values = [divisionId, image, contentType];
    conn.query(insert_user_query, values, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Database error:", err);
            return res.json({ error: "Failed while inserting data into database! Try to send files again." });
        }

        return res.json({ success: true });
    });
    }catch(err){
      return  res.status(500).json({ error: `Internal Server Error ${err}` });
    }
});
```

Comment: it says "Error: Multipart: Boundary not found"

Comment: ok you should remove the content-type from headers. i edited the code.